# Fedora desktop launcher

Tags: fedora, lxde, mime-types

I have created a desktop launcher for Midnight Commander in Fedora LXDE environment but this does not work. Where did I make a mistake?

```
$ cat mc.desktop 

[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=mc
Name[en_US]=mc
Name[ru_RU]=mc
Icon=mc_64
Exec=/home/uri/mc.sh
```

mc.sh is simple `bash -c '/usr/bin/mc'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mc` needs to run inside a terminal emulator, which is itself an application.  There are various terminal emulators (xterm, aterm, eterm); generally DEs (such as lxde) have one of their own -- in lxde's case, it's *lxterminal*.  Check what happens if you type `lxterminal &` on the command line ;)  With regard to your launcher, change the Exec line in *mc.desktop* to:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/lxterminal -e mc
```

Presuming that's where the executable is (check with `whereis lxterminal`). Alternately, you could change *mc.sh* to do the same thing, but the above is more straight-forward.

See `man lxterminal` for an explanation of the `-e` option.